# IntelliJ: Search for Checked exceptions, declared in method signature, but never thrown in body

Tags: java, intellij-idea, method-signature, checked-exceptions

I've got a rather simple IntelliJ/tool question here:
I'm currently dealing with some legacy code and started to rework stuff here and there. What I stumbled upon very often are declared (checked) exceptions in the method signature, although these exceptions are **never** thrown within the body.
These declarations are also **not** enforced by an interface or something alike, because this problem occurs mainly in MVC controllers, that apparently were always copied and pasted over and over again.
I would like to know if there's a way to search for such declared exceptions with IntelliJ.
Because if I put my caret at the `throws` keyword it does not highlight anything, because the declared exception is never thrown, but the editor does not show me an error marking either, what I would really appreciate : )
Is there an option in IntelliJ to enable this feature or does a plugin exist that would do that job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open settings, select `Editor` -`Inspections`. Find the `Java` - `Declaration reduncancy` - `Redundant throws clause` and tick it.

Then run code analysis, though `Analyze` - `Inspect code` on the top level menu.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, the problem was that this kind of analysis is only available on the fly if your methods are final/static. Without triggering `inspect code` I could not see it. Thanks : )

Answer (score 6):

```
Menu > Analyze > Run Inspection by Name > Redundant throws clause
```

enjoy:)